# Sorted set of a fixed size in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm a rookie in using Redis, and recently have a problem when I'm thinking the solution to handle the case of high concurrency in out system, I want to use Redis, everybody know access from In-Memory is great faster than IO. Redis sorted set is the possible tool for use to do it, we want to a fixed size of sorted set to contain the user's mobile number, I Googled/Baidued a lot, didn't find any meaning message, so can anybody tell me How to specify Redis Sorted Set a fixed size? And set should tell me any add operation to sorted set is success or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can specify a size, that you will have to check it yourself.

You can use [ZCARD](http://redis.io/commands/zcard)

```
ZCARD KEY
```

Or you could just remove the first element [ZREMRANGEBYRANK](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank)

```
[ZREMRANGEBYRANK][2] [KEY] 0 -[YOURSIZE]
```

Comment: `SCARD` is for regular (unsorted) Sets. Use `ZCARD`.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: I think you want "ZREMRANGEBYRANK [KEY] 0 -[YOURSIZE + 1]" to keep the [YOURSIZE] highest values

Comment: What would be the time complexity in case the sorted set hasn't exceeded 'YOURSIZE' or the expected limit? Would it be a constant time operation?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a lua script by checking the set size (`ZCARD`) before adding the element (`ZADD`). Complexity is `O(log(|setsize|))`   :

```lua
-- KEYS[1] the sorted set
-- ARGV[1] the score 
-- ARGV[2] the member 
-- ARGV[3] the max size of the sorted set 
-- Returns number of elements added
--
if redis.call('ZCARD', KEYS[1]) < tonumber(ARGV[3]) then
    return redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
else
    return 0    
end
```

You can try it out if you save the above snippet as `test.lua` file and then run it a few times, e.g

```
redis-cli --eval test.lua myset , 1 A 3
redis-cli --eval test.lua myset , 2 B 3
redis-cli --eval test.lua myset , 3 C 3
redis-cli --eval test.lua myset , 4 D 3
redis-cli --eval test.lua myset , 5 E 3
```

Verify

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myset 0 100
1) "A"
2) "B"
3) "C"
```