# Redis: clean up members of ZSET

Tags: redis

I'm currently studying Redis, and have the following case:

[image]

So what I have is a sorted set by google place id, for which all posts are sorted from recent to older. 
The first page that is requested fetches posts < current timestamp. 
When a cursor is sent to the backend, this cursor is a simple timestamp that indicates from where to fetch the next posts from the ZSET.
The query to retrieve posts by place id would be:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE <gplaceId> <cur_timestamp> -INF WITHSCORES LIMIT <offset:timestamp as from where to fetch> <count:number of posts>
```

My question is what is the recommended way to clean up members of the ZSET.
Since I want to use Redis as a cache, I would prefer to limit the number of posts per place for example up until 50. When places get new posts when already 50 posts have been added to the set, I want to drop the last post from the set.

Of course I realise that I could make a manual check on every insert and perform operations as such, but I wonder if Redis has a recommended way of performing this cleanup. Alternatively I could create a scheduler for this, but I would prefer not having to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Redis sorted set do not come with an out of the box feature for this. If sorted sets allowed a max size attribute with a configurable eviction strategy - you could have avoided some extra work.

See this related question:
[How to specify Redis Sorted Set a fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517012/how-to-specify-redis-sorted-set-a-fixed-size)

In absence of such a feature, the two approaches you mentioned are right.

1. You can replace inserts with a transaction : insert, check size, delete if > 50
2. A thread that checks size of the set and trims it periodically